# Query with LEFT JOIN on large table really slow

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, large-data

The following query takes approximately 12 seconds to execute. I have tried optimizing but was not able to. The table to be joined is pretty large (> 8.000.000 records).

```
SELECT 
    p0_.id AS id_0, 
    p0_.ean AS ean_1, 
    p0_.brand AS brand_2, 
    p0_.type AS type_3, 
    p0_.retail_price AS retail_price_4, 
    p0_.target_price AS target_price_5, 
    min(NULLIF(c1_.delivery_price, 0)) AS sclr_6, 
    COALESCE(((p0_.target_price - min(NULLIF(c1_.delivery_price, 0))) / p0_.target_price * -100), 0) AS sclr_7 
FROM product p0_ 
LEFT JOIN crawl c1_ ON (
    c1_.product_ean = p0_.ean AND (
        c1_.crawl_date = p0_.last_crawl_date OR 
        p0_.last_crawl_date IS NULL
    ) 
    AND c1_.source_id IN (
        SELECT o2_.source_id AS sclr_8 
        FROM organisation_source o2_ 
        WHERE o2_.organisation_id = 5
    )
) 
WHERE p0_.organisation_id = 5 GROUP BY p0_.ean
```

I already tried writing the query in a lot of different ways, but unfortunately did not give me any performance win. If I remove the subquery in the last AND it does not help either.

See below the output of the EXPLAIN statement:

```
+------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type  | table | type | possible_keys                                     | key              | key_len | ref                    | rows   | Extra       |
+------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | p0_   | ref  | uniqueConstraint,IDX_D34A04AD9E6B1585             | uniqueConstraint | 5       | const                  |     69 | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | c1_   | ref  | IDX_product_ean,IDX_crawl_date                    | IDX_product_ean  | 62      | admin_pricev-p.p0_.ean | 468459 | Using where |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | o2_   | ref  | PRIMARY,IDX_DD91A56E9E6B1585,IDX_DD91A56E953C1C61 | PRIMARY          | 4       | const                  |      1 | Using index |
+------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

See below the CREATE TABLE statements of the product and crawl tabel:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `retail_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `target_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `last_crawl_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueConstraint` (`organisation_id`,`ean`),
  KEY `IDX_D34A04AD9E6B1585` (`organisation_id`),
  KEY `IDX_target_price` (`target_price`),
  KEY `IDX_ean` (`ean`),
  KEY `IDX_type` (`type`),
  KEY `IDX_last_crawl_date` (`last_crawl_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D34A04AD9E6B1585` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=927 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `crawl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_ean` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `crawl_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `takeaway_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_B4E9F1C2953C1C61` (`source_id`),
  KEY `IDX_B4E9F1C2B092A811` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_product_ean` (`product_ean`),
  KEY `IDX_takeaway_price` (`takeaway_price`),
  KEY `IDX_crawl_date` (`crawl_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B4E9F1C2953C1C61` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B4E9F1C2B092A811` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8606874 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Anyone has any idea how to improve the performance of this query? Many thanks! If more information is needed please let me know!

Comment: What if you remove the `IN (SELECT ..)` part? Is that the slow part? You might rewrite that to another JOIN then.

Comment: Have you done indexing on the keys you are joining on like: c1_.product_ean & p0_.ean columns?

Comment: @Rudie thanks for you comment, I tried already by first manual running that query and getting the results directly into this query, but that did not help unfortunately.

Comment: @SirajulHaq Yes, the indexes are present (see also the create table statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably simplify the query to:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM product p0_  LEFT JOIN
     crawl c1_
     ON c1_.product_ean = p0_.ean AND 
        c1_.crawl_date = p0_.last_crawl_date AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM organisation_source o2_ 
                WHERE o2_.organisation_id = 5 AND c1_.source_id = o2_.source_id 
               )
WHERE p0_.organisation_id = 5
GROUP BY p0_.ean;
```

The `p0_.last_crawl_date IS NULL` is presumably unnecessary.  A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all rows in the first table even when there is a `NULL` in a comparison.  Your logic matches *all* rows in the second table (that meet the other conditions).  That may be what you want, but I am guessing not.

In MySQL, `exists` is sometimes faster than `in`, which is why I've rewritten that portion.

For this query, you can speed it up using indexes:  `product(organisation_id, ean, last_crawl_date)`, `crawl(product_ean, crawl_date, source_id)` and `organisation_source(source_id, organisation_id)`.

Comment: ok it seems that have been too slow again! I should really think to watch the chronometer whenever you're around  :)

Comment: Wow, just tried this one (without even adding the extra indexes) and it ran in 1.9 seconds, that is great! I will verify if the results are as I am expecting. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK you are a live safer, I was breaking my had over this query the last few days. We now brought it back (incl. indexes) from +/- 13 sec. back to a lousy 280ms :) Great! Many thanks.

Comment: @PeterBosch . . . 98% faster.  Not bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with composite indexes on your `LEFT JOIN`s

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `retail_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `target_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `last_crawl_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueConstraint` (`organisation_id`,`ean`),
  KEY `IDX_D34A04AD9E6B1585` (`organisation_id`),
  KEY `IDX_target_price` (`target_price`),
  KEY `IDX_ean` (`ean`),
  KEY `IDX_type` (`type`),
  KEY `IDX_last_crawl_date` (`last_crawl_date`),
  INDEX  `IDX_testing1` (`ean`,`last_crawl_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D34A04AD9E6B1585` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=927 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `crawl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_ean` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `crawl_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `takeaway_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_B4E9F1C2953C1C61` (`source_id`),
  KEY `IDX_B4E9F1C2B092A811` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_product_ean` (`product_ean`),
  KEY `IDX_takeaway_price` (`takeaway_price`),
  KEY `IDX_crawl_date` (`crawl_date`),
  INDEX  `IDX_testing2` ( `source_id`,`product_ean`,`crawl_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B4E9F1C2953C1C61` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B4E9F1C2B092A811` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8606874 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try with composites keys as Gordon also mentioned, that is a good tip!

Comment: If I only knew Gordon had answered in the meantime, I would not have posted anything. You can trust him ;)